# How enable c99 mode in gcc with terminal

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I want to activate c99 mode in gcc compiler to i read in other post in this forum that `-std` should be equal to `-std=c99` but i don't know how to set it to this value using command line so please help.

Comment: append your command with -std=c99 ;)

Comment: How do you specify the name of the executable?

Comment: Use the command `c99` to compile programs written in the language C99 ;-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Compile using:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o outputfile sourcefile.c
```

`gcc --help` lists some options, for a full list of options refer to the [manuals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). The different options for C dialect can be found the section "*Options Controlling C Dialect*" in any `gcc` version's manual (e.g., [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)).

As you are using `make` you can set the command line options for gcc using `CFLAGS`:

```
# sample makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99
OUTFILE = outputfile
OBJS = source.o
SRCS = source.c

$(OUTFILE): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OUTFILE) $(OBJS)
$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCS)
```

*Addendum (added late 2016): C99 is getting kind of old by now, people looking at this answer might want to explore **C11** instead.*

Comment: thanks but does this replace make because i always use make to compile all my programs ?

Comment: @user297904 No, if you use a makefile you should set the options in it instead. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks for the update one last question should write into terminal or inside of configuration file of make and where is the configuration file of make ?

Comment: @user297904 When you use make you have a makefile that tells make what to do when you invoke it. The sample I added is a basic makefile that compiles a c-file named source.c in the same directory and creates an executable file called `outputfile`

Comment: Two years after I wrote this I still get some upvotes, which of course is nice, but it might time to leave C99 behind and move on to newer standards (ie. using `-std=c11` for C11 instead).

Answer (score 6):

You may try to use the `-std=c99` flag.

Try to complile like this:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -g myProgram.c
```

Also note that `-g` is for debugging option(*Thanks Alter Mann for pointing that*).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments under another answer, perhaps you are using the implicit make rules and don't have a Makefile. If this, then you are just runing `make tst` to generate *tst* binary from *tst.c*. In that case you can specify the flags by setting the environment variable `CFLAGS`. You can set it for the current shell, or add it to your `~/.bashrc` to have it always, with this:

```
export CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -std=c99'
```

Or specifying it just for the single command:

```
CFLAGS='-Wall -Wextra -std=c99' make tst
```

(Note: I added warning flags too, you should really use them, they will detect a lot of potential bugs or just bad code you should write differently.)