# Dynamically Allocating a 2D Matrix of Structs in C

Tags: c, gcc, memory

I am writing a program in C which will read in an image in Bitmap format, and adjust some image parameters like colours, making the image greyscale, etc. I have the image loaded in, and have stored the image headers in 2 structs following Microsoft's documentation, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). I'm having trouble dynamically allocating memory for a 2D array which will serve as the new image to be written out. Each index in the matrix will be an RGB struct `PX_RGB`:

```
typedef struct RGB {
    BYTE rgbPK_BLUE;
    BYTE rgbPK_GREEN;
    BYTE rgbPK_RED;
} PX_RGB;
```

I've read a number of threads, most helpfully this one:
[Calloc a Two-Dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977084/calloc-a-two-dimensional-array?rq=1), and less helpfully this one:
[I have problems making a function to handle a matrix using calloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642570/i-have-problems-making-a-function-to-handle-a-matrix-using-calloc). (BYTE is just an alias for a uint8_t). If I naively allocate based solely off of the number of bytes in the input image and the size of the `struct`s:

```
PX_RGB *new_image = calloc(img_information.bi_size_image, sizeof(PX_RGB));
```

I'm unable to index it as I would like to, like a matrix (i.e. `new_image[i][j] = ...`
The comments and responses from the first thread seem to indicate placing one of the image dimensions on the left-hand side and allocating this way:

```
PX_RGB (*new_image)[image_width] = calloc(image_height, image_width * sizeof(PX_RGB));
```

But the compiler isn't happy about this, as the size of any potential image isn't known at compile time. There's also a different solution, but this just doesn't seem to do anything - neither the check for `NULL` neither the code trying to index it seems to do anything:

```
PX_RGB **new_image;
new_image = calloc(image_height, image_width * sizeof(new_image));

if (new_image == NULL) { printf("\nError: Could not allocate image memory.\n"); return -1; }
for (int i = 0; i < image_height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image_width; j++)
    {
        new_image[i][j].rgbPK_BLUE = j;
        printf("\nIndex [%d][%d] = %d", i, j, new_image[i][j].rgbPK_BLUE);
    }
}
```

I had seen this used as an answer in the first thread, but there the number of columns needed was known and hard-coded in ([3]).
I came across this formula for getting the correct row offset [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays), and with this test code seems to work fine, I think:

```
PX_RGB *new_image = calloc(image_height, image_width * sizeof(new_image));

int offset = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < image_height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image_width; j++)
    {
        offset = (j * image_width) + i;
        new_image[offset].rgbPK_BLUE = j;
        printf("\nIndex [%d][%d] = %d", i, j, new_image[offset].rgbPK_BLUE);
    }
}
```

So, is there no way to index dynamically allocated memory the way I want to? I would ideally like to pass my new image to the manipulation functions like this:

```
void grayscale(int image_height, int image_width, PX_RGB new_image[image_height][image_width])
{
    return;
}
```

because I have seen other code doing this and I'm stumped why I can't get my version working, and what I'm doing wrong. I should say I got the idea for this project from an open lecture series on computer science by Harvard on edX, where they seemed to have implemented this logic in the way that I want to. Help would be hugely appreciated, cheers!

Comment: "compiler isn't happy about this, as the size of any potential image isn't known at compile time" --> One way out, use a C99 compiler or later that supports [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the response - I had seen this mentioned in another thread. I checked my compiler version with `gcc -v`, and I'm on `mingw-w64 8.1.0`, on Windows. I remember downloading this at least in the last 6 months. Are there any compiler flags I need to pass to specify a C version?

Comment: Try [How enable c99 mode in gcc with terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566597/how-enable-c99-mode-in-gcc-with-terminal/25566648)

Comment: GCC 8 defaults to C11 conformance + extensions, including support for the optional (in C11) VLA feature.  It should accept the `PX_RGB (*new_image)[image_width]` variation, provided that a declaration of `image_width` as an integer variable is in scope, and that variable has been assigned a positive value.  This is among the cleanest options available, so if it's not working for you then a bit more detail on exactly what you're trying and on what GCC says about it would be in order.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as matrix with little trick as :

```
new_image[i][j] == *(new_image + (i*num_of_columns) + j);
```

Because two dimention array is nothing but a linear array with continuous memory allocation.
Or otherwise, you can typecast it as

```
typedef Px_RGB (*ptype)[no_of_columns];
ptype new_image_indexed = (ptype)new_image;
```

Now new_image_indexed can be accessed as

```
new_image_indexed[i][j];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I mentioned the first row-wise indexing method you mentioned somewhere in my original post.
Your typedef idea is pretty neat though, I may use that as a backup up all else fails.